How do I use Operators on parsed/converted strings?
I've begun learning C# and I was tasked with creating a piece of code that calculates the area of a rectangle or given object. I wanted to take this further, and I've tried to create a program that takes the width and length from the user and calculates the area with it.
To do this I parsed to convert the variables holding the User's inputs into int's, however when I try to multiply the variables I get the following error:

Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
'string'

Here is the code in it's entirety:
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, would you like me to calculate the area of your rectangle? input anything to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        
        Console.WriteLine("Please give me the Length of the rectangle:");
        String User_Length =Console.ReadLine();
        int.Parse(User_Length);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Please give me the Width of your rectangle");
        String User_Width =Console.ReadLine();
        Convert.ToInt32(User_Width);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Here is the Area of you rectangle: " + User_Length * User_Width);
    }
}


I also tried a different converting method being Convert.ToInt32(User_Width); however this yielded the same result.
I additionally tried to put the parse codes before the string however this also yields an error.

You need to assign the value returned by int.Parse(User_Length) to a variable, e.g., int rectHeight = int.Parse(User_Length). (It's normal to use width and height for the dimensions of a rectangle.)

(There are plenty of free C# introductory tutorials available, e.g., you can get the PDF of C# Yellow Book - I have no connection to it.)

So , the misconception in the question is that int.Parse(User_Length) changes the type of User_Length into an int - it does not: the type of User_Length will always be a string. (Also, you may not want to read it, but What is the difference between String and string in C#?)

C# is a strongly typed language.

Related https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-8.0#system-convert-toint32(system-string)

int.Parse(User_Length); does not modify the User_Length variable. Instead, it returns the value as a result; you need to assign the result to a variable. Since C# is strongly-typed and User_Length is a string variable, you will not be able to assign it to User_Length. You must have a separate int variable. There is no way to change a variable from one type to another.
int user_Length = int.Parse(User_Length);

Then you will be able to do math operations with the numeric variable.

Same applies for Convert.ToInt32(User_Width). That function does exactly the same and also returns an int.

I would also stringly recommend to name both variables differently to differentiate between them. Changing only the case of one (even though it's totally valid) can make things confussing for the next reader of the code.
